# Java Poem Palindrome Checker: Iterate through array matching elements in order

Tags: java, arrays, loops, palindrome

Currently trying to program a poem Palindrome checker. This is not for palindromes specifically, but that the array has words in the same order both ways. For example the following is a poem palindrome

```
Life-
imitates nature,
always moving, traveling continuously.
Continuously traveling, moving always,
nature imitates
life
```

My issue is iterating through the array to match the first and last elements, as currently it compares things in the wrong order.

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class WordPalindromeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This program determines if an entered sentence/word poem is a palindrome.");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string to determine if it is a palindrome: ");
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            String palin = input.nextLine();
            if(palin.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                boolean isPalin = isWordPalindrome(palin);
                if(isPalin == true) {
                    System.out.println(palin + " is a palindrome!");
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println(palin + " is NOT  a palindrome!");
                }
            }

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        input.close();

    }

    public static boolean isWordPalindrome(String s) {
        boolean isWordPal = false;
        String lowerCase = s.toLowerCase();
        String replaced = lowerCase.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
        String words[] = replaced.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if (words[i].equals(words[j]) && i != j) {
                    isWordPal = true;
                }
                else
                    isWordPal = false;
            }
        }
        return isWordPal;
    }
}
```

With the specific point in question being

```
public static boolean isWordPalindrome(String s) {
        boolean isWordPal = false;
        String lowerCase = s.toLowerCase();
        String replaced = lowerCase.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
        String words[] = replaced.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if (words[i].equals(words[j]) && i != j) {
                    isWordPal = true;
                }
                else
                    isWordPal = false;
            }
        }
        return isWordPal;
    }
```

I am confused on how to properly set up the loop to compare the right elements. It should compare the first element to the last, the second to the second to last, etc. until the loop is finished. I realize I have it compare the first to the entire array before moving on.

Comment: The biggest mistake in your code is that there are no comments. You should write your algorithm in English first, in comments. Then you should translate it into code after. Keep the comments. Code should be documented, either self documented (a skill few coders have) by the way it's written, or explained in comments. Like the part where you can get 90% on an exam full of wrong answers, if you show workings. You're new to the sport and probably don't think in code yet. Complex algorithms should always be written in the language you think in, and then translated to the language you're learning.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a homework assignment so I won't give you a working solution. But this of it like this:

-You don't need two loops. You only need to compare the first to the last, the second to the second to last, etc. (Hint: if you subtract `i-1` from the length of the `Array` you'll get the corresponding element to `i` that you need to compare to). Also you only need to iterate over half of the length of the `Array`

-If ever `isWordPal` becomes false, you need to `return` false. Otherwise it might get overwritten and at the end it will return true.

Comment: Another tip, you only need to run a loop that iterates for half of an array length

Comment: @CaiusJard That's true. I edited that in. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I figured using two loops was incorrect. Would the subtraction take place during the declaration of the loop, or afterwards in an if statement? `for(int i = 0; i < words.length-1; i++` or say `if(words[i].equals(words[words.length-(i-1))` Thanks for the help!

Comment: @gblodgett Ps don't be surprised if someone marks you down for this answer, because in the pure "doing their homework for them" sense, it's not an answer.. I support your encouraging of self thinking and learning, btw, but there's bound to be some moaning purist along at some point.. :)

Comment: @CaiusJard I figured that would happen, but I thought it might be different since I am asking for one specific part of a problem i've mostly solved myself. I don't want people to do my homework for me as it doesn't help me in the long run, but for some reason this problem is raking my brain

Comment: @Swinda You only have to loop until `words.length/2`. And you're missing a closing `]` int `words.length - (i -1))`. Also you don't need the parenthesis. Simply `[words.length - i - 1]` will suffice. It sounds like you're on the right track

Comment: @swinda yes, the loop logic is wrong primarily because both your loops run in the same direction, so you end up comparing the first word of one array with the first word of another array. Your follow up question of where to do this is easiy answred by you switching off the computer and sitting down with pencil and paper and writing down the algorithm. Try it. Even pro coders don't immediately jump to a text editors and start writing complex stuff as code

Comment: @GBlodgett Thank you for the help! Figured it out. Did an if statement check, and fixed my return statements as well. `if(words[i] != words[words.length -1 -i]){ return false; } `. Took me a bit as I accidentally mistyped words as word... Thank you again!

Comment: that can be an even  aside kistake to makenin other languages like c# because by default strings are treated like arrays of characters, so you can write code that you think is accessing the first string in an array of strings (`words[0]) but is actually accessing the first character of a single string (word[0]) - one to be mindful of